# Error class "app\Models\BlogPost" not found

Tags: laravel, controller, xampp, laravel-8, laravel-models

I'm using a MySQL (XAMPP) database, which I have linked in the .env file of my Laravel folder. I'm trying to use the database to show "blog posts" on the posts.index page, and it isn't showing any errors in visual studio code, but when I go to the page in my browser, it shows this error:

> Error Class "app\Models\BlogPost" not found http://laravel.test/posts

**PostsController**

```
class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('posts.index', ['posts' => BlogPost::all()]);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        // abort_if(!isset($this->posts[$id]), 404);

        return view('posts.show', ['post' => BlogPost::findorFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

**BlogPost Model**

```
class BlogPost extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Update: The issue I have now is that I see the item array. (I'm a Laravel beginner, so I don't always see the problems in the code).

This is the post.index code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Blog Posts')

@section('content')
{{--  @each('posts.partials.post', $posts, 'post')  --}}
@dd($posts)
@forelse ($posts as $key => $post)
    @include('posts.partials.post', [])
     @empty
     No posts found!    
    @endforelse
@endsection
```

This is what I see in the browser (instead of what's in the database)

```
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\BlogPost {#1233 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "blog_posts"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▶]
      #original: array:5 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Comment: Typo: `app` vs `App`

Comment: You could always take a look at the documentation. In your case: [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd)

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: The problem is that that's what I already see in the browser. I'll add it to the question

Comment: That's why I suggested to read the documentation, and specifically linked to [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd) for you to read. From that page: "_The dd function dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script_"

Comment: Yes I see! You've fixed my problem entirely, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. May be it has an issue with namespace in BlogPost model.

if you use this code for Category Model in your PostsController controller:

use App\Models\BlogPost ;
then your BlogPost model itself has this namespace

namespace App\Models;
Check if your model namespace is still there or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of using `@dd($posts)` in blade. Just delete `@dd($posts)`.